# jython: directory contains neither jython-dev.jar nor jython.jar

Tags: python, jython-2.7

I am trying to install jython 2.7 from jython.org, i installed verything in full mode.

yet, when accessed the bin directory, run jython executable, i get the error:

> /usr/local contains neither jython-dev.jar nor jython.jar.
>   Try running this script from the 'bin' directory of an installed Jython or 
>   setting $JYTHON_HOME.
>   usage: jython [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
>   Try `jython -h' for more information.

is there any solution ? i tried a shell script execution for jython but it did not work.

Thankyou !

Comment: Did you check whether /usr/local contains jython-dev.jar and jython.jar ? Did you follow the suggestion to setting $JYTHON_HOME?

Comment: Hello Yi, i just set $JYTHON_HOME this morning and it worked. Thank you ! for reference: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7697/6niuibtkq/index.html